# issue importing database into phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

When trying to import a drupal database into phpMyAdmin on my local xampp server I first had an issue with the size of the .sql file I was trying to upload. I resolved this issue by updating my phpmyadmin to the latest version and changing the following settings in my php.ini files.

```
memory_limit=255M 
post_max_size=200M 
upload_max_filesize=150M
```

Now I was able to upload the file but I ran into a different error, namely:

```
Error 
Static analysis
1 error was found during analysis
 1. missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL-query:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
MySQL reports:
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

I'm not sure if these changes had anything to do with me being unable to import a database as it is the first time i'm trying to import a database.
I'm new to phpmyadmin and I'm not sure what to do...

(side note: I installed a wampserver and tried to import a database there but ran into the same error)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed my problem by entering following code into the sql command line on phpMyAdmin:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```